# I want to upload data from Excel and store in SQL Server at the time of save the format is changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I imported data from Excel and save into a temp table and after that it will save in main table and temp table will be `truncate.all` data are save properly only issue in date format because in Excel it was `DD/MM/YYYY` but at the time of save it save in `MM/DD/YYYY` in SQL Server.

How can I save `MM/DD/YYYY` time to `DD/MM/YYYY` in SQL Server?

I tried many solutions and I didn't get any positive result. Even tried to convert in query also but same result reflected.

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string FilePath = Convert.ToString(Session["FilePath"]);

        string conString = string.Empty;
        string Filename = Session["Filename"].ToString();

        //string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string extension = Filename.Substring(Filename.LastIndexOf('.'));

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;

        }

        conString = string.Format(conString, FilePath);

        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            //string sheet1 = "Index Of Charge";

            //string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[1]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[9] { 
            new DataColumn("SNo", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("SRN", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Charge Id",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Charge Holder Name",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Date of Creation",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Date of Modification",typeof(string)), 
            new DataColumn("Date of Satisfaction",typeof(string)), 
            new DataColumn("Amount",typeof(decimal)), 
            new DataColumn("Address",typeof(string))});
            //new DataColumn("CreatedDate",typeof(string)),
            //new DataColumn("ModifiedDate",typeof(string)),
            //new DataColumn("CreatedBy",typeof(int))});
            string sheet1 = DdlSheetNames.SelectedItem.Text;

            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }

            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.INDEXOFCHARGE";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SNo", "SNo");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SRN", "SRN");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Charge Id", "ChargeId");

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Charge Holder Name", "ChargeHolderName");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date of Creation", "DateofCreation");

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date of Modification", "DateofModification");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date of Satisfaction", "DateofSatisfaction");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount", "Amount");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Address", "Address");

                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        //update Fields
        Myconn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_InsetCreatedby", Myconn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.UpdateDateFormat", Myconn);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Myconn.Close();

        //update complete

        //show Details

        ShowDetails_Click(sender, e);
        //show details complete
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    //show Details complete
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
    {
        string FolderName = "BasicDetails";
        string Filename = FileUpload1.FileName;

        Session["Filename"] = FileUpload1.FileName;

        string RightNm = Filename.Substring(Filename.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        int FileLen = RightNm.Length;



        string LeftNm = Filename.Substring(0, Convert.ToInt32(Filename.Length) - (FileLen + 1)).ToString();
        Filename = LeftNm + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyy") + "." + RightNm;

        bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(FolderName));

        if (!folderExists)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(FolderName));

        string path = Server.MapPath(FolderName) + "\\" + Filename;
        Session["FilePath"] = path;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

        string conString = string.Empty;
        OleDbConnection excelConnection;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;

        }

        conString = string.Format(conString, path);

        excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        excelConnection.Open();
        DataTable Sheets = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        int rowcnt = 0;
        DdlSheetNames.Items.Add("-Select-");

        foreach (DataRow dr in Sheets.Rows)
        {
            string sht = dr[2].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sht + "]", excelConnection);

            rowcnt = rowcnt + 1;
            DdlSheetNames.Items.Add(sht);
        }

        excelConnection.Close();
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to cast the column in the sheet as Date using the very Excel and also change the dataColumn to "Date of Modification",typeof(DateTIme)?

Comment: If you did not receive any error during import regarding dates it may be that you are dealing with different presentation of dates in excel and sql server. Do try to add excel columns that will show month and day of appropriate fields and query sql server in the same manner to check if those additional fields matches.

Answer (score 0):

You know, the date format doesn't matter in SQL Server.  Just make sure the field you are passing dates to is of data type DATE.  Remember, the format of the data is the appearance of the data, but the underlying data itself doesn't change.  If you want to change the format, you can do it like this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

Also, consider this.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [ToDateTime] = [ContainedData]
```

Finally, you should bookmark the link below.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx